# Script in IE to Insert Text at Cursor (in or out of IE)

Tags: scripting, clipboard

I need to take text already obtained and stored in a variable and place it in another window: IE or any other windows application.

Context:
An asynchronous application is running in IE, most likely in the background, and when an event fires in the application, certain text needs to be inserted wherever the cursor/carrot is.

I am not restricted to any particular technology so if it even needs to be an ActiveX component I am open to anything.

This is something due for a project by the end of the week so ANY suggestions/ideas are VERY welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write an ActiveX control that calls the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

However, this sounds like a dumb idea.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't even get me started :)  I was instructed to do so. After numerous arguments, I gave up for many reasons.  The point is to take an account number that is sent to an application we have control over and place it in a supplementary application we do NOT have control over.  They will be waiting for this event to fire and once it has, all they should have to do is click a button because our application has placed the value we have and they need in the text box they currently are sitting in. Worse: we are considering converting to a cross-platform version.

Comment: It is physically impossible to write a cross-platform version.